# Knockoutjs: hide image when emty or null

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement knockoutjs for the first time in a web page. I stumbled into the following problem, but maybe it is also a case of "best practices".

I have a product page, and a product can have a product image. When there is no product image available, the property is set to null and I need to show a "no image available" picture.

My model:

```
function ProductOverview() {
     var self = this;

     self.guid = ko.observable();
     self.Image = ko.observable();
     self.IsActive = ko.observable(false);
}
```

My viewmodel:

```
function productOverviewModelView() {
var self = this;

self.productOverview = new ProductOverview();
self.ShowNoImage = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.productOverview.Image() === null || self.productOverview.Image() === "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, this);
self.ImageAvailable = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.productOverview.Image() === null || self.productOverview.Image === "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, this);

//whenever the device is changed call this function
self.selectedProduct.subscribe(function () {
    if (self.selectedProduct === "") {
        self.productOverview = null;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "productoverview.aspx/getdevice",
            data: "{'guid':'" + self.selectedProduct() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var product = JSON.parse(unescape(data.d));
                self.productOverview.guid(product.guid);
                self.productOverview.Image(product.Image);
                self.productOverview.IsActive(product.IsActive);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

My view:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <img alt="" src="#" data-bind="attr: { src: productOverview.Image }" />
  <img alt="" src="../../images/no-image-available.jpg" data-bind="visible:ShowNoImage" />
</div>
```

It works, but like this it is not working:

```
<img alt="" src="../../images/no-image-available.jpg" data-bind="visible: productOverview.Image != ''" />
```

*Is there a shorter way, instead of making the computed observables?*

I also wanted to show an active image when the product is active:

```
<img src="../../images/active_icon.gif" data-bind="visible: productOverview.isActive" />
```

*But this image is not showing, why?*

And the other way around, can I also show the inactive image like this?

```
<img src="../../images/notactive_icon.gif" data-bind="visible: !productOverview.isActive" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've worked out a jsFiddle example regarding your questions: http://jsfiddle.net/XAXKZ/5

You've made some mistakes:

- isActive and IsActive mixed up. JavaScript is still case sensitive. And you need to show it as a function:

`data-bind="visible: !IsActive()"`

- You can also test other variables this way, without the need to add dedicated functions for it:

`data-bind="visible:productOverview.Image() == '' || productOverview.Image() == null"`

Answer (score 0):

You should call the observable like this :

```
<img src="../../images/notactive_icon.gif" data-bind="visible: productOverview.isActive() " />
```

It's because isActive is a function so it's never  null

Comment: I already tried that, but when the page is loaded, I receive the following error: `Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: productOverview.isActive is not a function;
Bindings value: visible: productOverview.isActive()`